# Does an NDX400-equivalent exist for a 95mm filter thread?

Tags: filters, telephoto, neutral-density, filter-diameter

I found [this beauty](http://www.f64.ro/products/description/Samyang_650_1300mm_F_8_MC_IF_focalizare_manuala-pentru_montura_T2/index.html) at a low price and I would like to shoot the sun. That would require me to use an [NDX400](http://www.hoyafilter.com/products/hoya/oef-07.html) but I can't find it for a 95mm filter screw. Does it even exist?

Comment: By the chart on Hoya's page for that filter, _no_, so let's expand this to looking for alternatives too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not hung up on the Hoya brand name, you can get neutral density filters in [2.4](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Density%20%28ND%29_2.7%20%289-stops%29&ci=114&N=4256189595%204242329427), [2.7](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Density%20%28ND%29_2.7%20%289-stops%29&ci=114&N=4256189595%204242329427) and [3.0](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Density%20%28ND%29_3.0%20%2810-stops%29&ci=114&N=4256189595%204242329426) log densities (8, 9 and 10 stops) in the large square formats for Lee and Cokin filter holders, which will also make them usable on your other lenses. (The links are to product list pages at B&H.)

Comment: How many stops does a NDX400 have? The idea was to be able to safely shoot the sun (safe for me and for the camera).

Comment: @Andrei: The NDX400 is a nine-stop filter (2.7 log density), so I gave you a stop on either side as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a full-aperture solar filter that's appropriate for astronomy use.  Orion sells many: http://www.telescope.com/catalog/search.cmd?form_state=searchForm&keyword=solar+filter

Advantage of this kind is that it would be safe to look through with your eyes.

Comment: I must check out the thread type and diameter, maybe there even are adapters so I could pluck a larger filter?

Comment: Most of these solar filters fit over the end of the lens.  They usually have a bit of gap to allow set screws for a snug fit.  Given that the filter diameter of the lens you are using is 95mm, I'm guessing that a 4.10 inch diameter solar filter should drop over the hood of it readily.